# How to run in C# CMD with admin rights with password and then save all output to a string?

Tags: c#, batch-file, cmd

I would like to run **"runas /user:Administrator C:\Info.bat"** in CMD. Admin user requires password which is **("pass")**. When I confirm password I got data that I would like to save it into a string.

Here is my code:

```
        // admin password with secure string
        var pass = new SecureString();
        pass.AppendChar('p');
        pass.AppendChar('a');
        pass.AppendChar('s');
        pass.AppendChar('s');

        Process p = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("CMD");
        startInfo.Verb = "runas";

        //go to user -> Administrator and then to file C:\\Info.bat (not working)
        startInfo.Arguments = "/user:Administrator C:\\Info.bat";
        startInfo.Password = pass;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo = startInfo;

        // save all output data to string
        p.Start();
```

Why second argument not working to **run C:\Info.bat**?

How can I **save all cmd output text to a string**?

Thanks for help.

Comment: what does "not working" mean exactly? You get an error? Or some other unexpected behaviour?

Comment: try this and let me know => `startInfo.Arguments = "/user:Administrator \"cmd /K  C:\\Info.bat\"";`

Comment: Thanks @er-shoaib that run C:\Info.bat.

Comment: should i add above code as answer to your question?

Comment: Please and thanks.

Comment: @LukaToni, answer added you can mark the tick on left side of answer to make it green and also vote up by clicking up arrow to answer :)

Comment: @er-shoaib that is only part of solution. I need to save all output CMD data to a string, which is my main question.

Comment: @LukaToni, plz provide some data inside `Info.bat` so i can write code on my side?

Comment: @LukaToni, i update my answer to read cmd data to string kindly view **Edit** section in answer :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183973/discussion-between-luka-toni-and-er-shoaib).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your process argument like below

```
startInfo.Arguments = "/user:Administrator \"cmd /K C:\\Info.bat\"";
```

**/K** argument, which tells CMD.exe to open, run the specified command, then keep the window open.

You may also use.

**/C** argument, which tells CMD.exe to open, run the specified command, then close when it's done.

**Edit:**

Here you can read output of your `info.bat` file in string variable.

```
var pass = new SecureString();
pass.AppendChar('p');
pass.AppendChar('a');
pass.AppendChar('s');
pass.AppendChar('s');

Process p = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("CMD");
startInfo.Verb = "runas";

startInfo.Arguments = "/user:Administrator \"cmd /C  C:\\info.bat\"";
startInfo.Password = pass;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;   
p.StartInfo = startInfo;

p.Start();

string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
```